# How can you be a brahmachari if marrying is compulsory for Hindus

Tags: dharma, marriage, brahmacharya

> Brahmacharya … means to stay in conduct within one's own Self.

> … brahmacharya implies, among other things, the mandatory renunciation of sex and marriage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmacharya

> … Brahmacarya (celibacy) … – these are roots of Dharma …

[Vayu Purana I.57.116](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52542/what-do-our-hindu-scriptures-mention-about-helping-people)

> In the Shastric Hindu law, marriage has been regarded as one of the essential sanakaras (sacrament for every Hindu). Every Hindu must marry. “To be mothers were woman created and to be fathers men.” The Veda ordains that “Dharma must be practiced by man together with his wife and offspring”. “He is only perfect who consists of his wife and offspring.” “Those who have wives can fulfill their obligations in this world; those who have wives truly have a family life; those who have wives can be happy; those who have wives can have a full life.” For a Hindu marriage is essential, not only for begetting a son in order to discharge his debt to the ancestors, but also for performance of other religious and spiritual duties.

[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3705690/#:~:text=In%20the%20Shastric,and%20spiritual%20duties](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3705690/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Shastric,and%20spiritual%20duties).

> Amongst the most prominent Hindu wedding ritual is 'seven vows or Saptapadi which are performed along with Mangal Pheras (walking around the sacred fire). … couple stand equally and promises each other lifelong companionship.

[https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog/seven-vows-hindu-wedding/#:~:text=Amongst%20the%20most%20prominent%20Hindu,promises%20each%20other%20lifelong%20companionship](https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog/seven-vows-hindu-wedding/#:%7E:text=Amongst%20the%20most%20prominent%20Hindu,promises%20each%20other%20lifelong%20companionship).

Comment: The word Brahma (God) charya (Walking toward or on the path of God or towards). literal meaning is one who walks towards or on the path of god. Cannot have sexual urge towards opposite sex because they are above that. now the word is used for wrong purpose one who abstain from sex it doesnt mean that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brahmacharya and Gṛhasthāśrama are two different stages of life.

A person was in brahmacharya when he was a student, under a guru. He was expected to marry after completing his education, but that was not compulsory; many chose to become ascetics and stay in a permanent state of brahmacharya.

Sanyasins must practice lifelong brahmacharya and cannot marry. Their indebtment to their pitṛs is annulled as they enter sannyāsa, when they perform balitarpaṇam to their ancestors, living parents and their own souls.

Those who have not given up worldly life were expected to fulfill the debt to their pitṛs by marrying and producing virtuous children.